# How to use Matlab's fminunc for steepest descent?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I already have a working code with this part:

```
  Jold = 1e6; J = 0;
  while abs(Jold - J) > 1e-5                        
     Jold = J;                                      
     Jb = 2*(X - Xb)' / B * (X - Xb);               
     Jo = 2*(Y - H*X)' / R * (Y - H*X);             
     J = Jb + Jo;                                    
     gJ = 2 ./ B *(X - Xb) - 2*H'/ R *(Y - H*X);      
     X = X - alpha*gJ;                              
  end
```

We want to minimze the cost function *J=Jo+Jb* with respect to *X*. We do this by steepest descent, where *alpha* is the step size. *gJ* is the gradient of J. *Xb*, *Y*, *B* and *R* can be considered constants for the purpose of minimization. In this particular example, *H=I*, identity matrix. The code itself is taken from [here](http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~hakim/591/code/L63_3dvar.m), a 3DVAR algorithm to solve Lorentz attractor.

I want to replace all of this with fminunc. This is Matlab's implementation of unconstrained optimization. The function takes a function handler plus a range. I tried:

```
 fun = @(X) Jb + Jo;
 options = optimoptions(@fminunc,'Algorithm','quasi-Newton');
 X3 = fminunc (fun, [0, 1],options);
```

But it is just giving me the rage I provide, whatever the range is.

Answer (score 1):

`fun=@(X) Jb+Jo` is not a valid function, I assume you have already defined `Jo` and `Jb` as matrices, so this will not change for different `X`. You need to have the `X` dependence explicitly in `fun`:

```
fun=@(X) 2*(X-Xb).'/B*(X-Xb) + 2*(Y-H*X).'/R*(Y-H*X);
```

or you could still define `Jo` and `Jb`, but as functions of `X`, and use them to define `fun`:

```
Jb =@(X) 2*(X-Xb).'/B*(X-Xb);     %// Now Jo and Jb are function handles,
Jo =@(X) 2*(Y-H*X).'/R*(Y-H*X);   %// not vectors/matrices!
fun=@(X) Jo(X)+Jb(X);
```

I think `fminunc` should be happy with that.

Comment: That's a good point, but I'm getting different error about matrix dimension not matching in the fun. I tried changeing [0 1] initialization vector to [zeros(3,1), ones(3,1)\, but still not working. I know that X, Xb and Y are all 3x1, while B and R are 3x3, so this is weird.

Comment: Well in that case, what do you mean by dividing by the matrix `B`?

Comment: Maybe you should have `(X-Xb).'./(B*(X-Xb))` so you do the `B*(X-Xb)` first, which results in a 3x1 vectors, then do the elemnt-wise division (which probably doesn't need the transpose: `(X-Xb)./(B*(X-Xb))`.

Comment: It is actually complaining about the subtraction, so I guess the problem is that X is an element, not a vector, in the anonymous function. We need to define the function to be a function of vector X, not element X.

Comment: Check the size of each variable that goes into the definition of `fun` on the line before you define it, that will show you which one is wrong.